# What if I don't want to work at "Rochester Institute ofï¿½"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising, encoding

As I was closing terrible questions, I noticed something strange in the Careers ad:

[image]

There appears to be an encoding problem. I'm not sure what is supposed to be there, but it shows `ï¿½` instead.

More examples:

- [Leadership for Educationalï¿½](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72869/salesforce-report-writer-leadership-for-educational) instead of [Leadership for Educational Equity](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72869/salesforce-report-writer-leadership-for-educational).
- [Stansberry and Associatesï¿½](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/74397/cloud-devops-engineer-baltimore-md-stansberry-and-associates) instead of [Stansberry and Associates Investment Research](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/74397/cloud-devops-engineer-baltimore-md-stansberry-and-associates).

It appears to only happen to companies that have long names.

---

I just found out that `ï¿½` is the UTF-8 representation of `�`, which is the Unicode replacement character. See [this answer at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367675/2846923) for more information.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/73374/systems-analyst-rochester-institute-of?a=oBEHPubSWre "Rochester Institute of Technology"

Comment: @Bart But it might be one of those things where they just put a `…` instead of the entire long name.

Comment: So just don't :)

Comment: I just do the pointy-look-at-that-thingy here @TheGuywithTheHat. I'll leave actual analysis and solution up to the developers while I go "tsk tsk tsk, how can you be so dumb" from the sidelines. ;)

Comment: Well, those strange characters are the Unicode Replacement Character as can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488866/how-to-replace-%C3%AF-%C2%BD-in-a-string).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually no. The Unicode Replacement Character is [�](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). There appears to be an encoding issue in that question that replaces `�` with `ï¿½`.

Comment: *bets is a ellipsis*

Comment: … ... … ... … ...

Comment: @Braiam is correct. The … character somehow got replaced with the `ï¿½` character(s?) during a source code refactoring.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, *that's* not good. We recently made a change as to how the content for those job listings gets generated, and that particular little glitch somehow sneaked through.

There will be a fix up shortly. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Fix is being pushed out presently. You should start seeing those replaced with proper `…` characters in a few minutes.

Answer (score 19):

Long time ago, a friend of mine replied to tester's mail complaining about `ï¿½` appearing somewhere in documentation of his project:

> You don't understand, these are special symbols carrying important meaning. 'I' with two dots means we dotted all `i`s and crossed all `t`s. Question mark turned upside down means there are no more questions left. Half-sign means the project is already half way through to being totally perfect.

Unfortunately, he didn't quote above in the bug tracker. Instead, he put some boring evaluation there, like "this is an encoding issue" and fixed it.